# JavaFx KeyEvent won't move object

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent

I am currently trying to just make a really simple game as an experiment of what can be done with JavaFX, and I have a little rectangle that represents a person. The rectangle is set in a pane, and I'm trying to figure out how best to make it so the arrow keys make him  move 5 px over to the left. The code below is what I'm trying. If you know how to make this code work or have better code for it, I would be very grateful.

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            if(ke.equals(KeyCode.KP_LEFT)) {
                int xLoc = (int)avatar.getX();
                int newX = xLoc - 5;
                int yLoc = (int)avatar.getY();
                avatar.relocate(newX, yLoc);
            }
        }
    });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `KeyEvent` is not the code, you need `getCode()`.

```
if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.KP_LEFT))
```

Comment: Furthermore since `KP_LEFT` is an enum constant, `==` suffices to compare the values.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Still though, the character will not move. Any ideas?

Comment: @PorterFarley At this point, it is hard to further deduce without providing more codes. We need to know what `avatar` is and how it is declared/defined. We definitely need to know what that `relocate()` method does. Also, placing breakpoint while running debugging would help you to debug this as well; does `avatar.relocate()` even execute at runtime?

Comment: KP_Left -> You are using the number pad left. Make sure Num Lock is off.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I'm still fairly new to Stack and didn't really know what to do. I found a seperate solution by using on screen buttons to make movement, but I'll make sure to change these things in any further questions I ask. Thank you again.